# When conducting a meta-analysis using Pearson's R as the effect size, should you include perfect values (i.e., r = 1.00)?

Tags: spss, meta-analysis, pearson-r

I'm in the process of conducting a meta-analysis of clinical research.

Since most of the included studies report Pearson's R as the effect size, I've decided to use that as the meta-analysis statistic. Some of these values are perfect values (i.e., r = 1.00).

I am planning to use Field and Gillett's SPSS syntax to do the meta-analysis.

However, when I use their syntax it throws a bunch of errors when I include the perfect values and only produces the Hunter-Schmidt results. These don't seem to represent the data I've put into the calculation, as it produces a very small average effect size when it is more likely to be medium or large based on the raw data.

I'm wondering if I should remove these perfect values from the meta-analysis calculation or if I should round them down to something that is basically 1.00 (i.e., 0.999). When I remove them or round them down, the syntax works and produces results that make sense. I am just not sure if this is good practice, statistically speaking.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the software you are using transforms them into Fisher's $z$ (the inverse hyperbolic arctangent).

What you suggest is a plausible way forward but note that the value of $z$ is quite sensitive to small changes near unity. For r=0.99 it gives 2.65, for r=0.999 it gives 3.80,
and for r=0.9999 it gives 4.95. It might be a good idea to use several values to make sure your outcome if not unduly sensitive to your exact choice.